# Set theory - distributive laws

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to show
$(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) \cup (A \cap B) = A \cup B $, so pretty clear that this holds
I would like to show it with an algebraic proof

I started :

$x∈(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)\cup(A \cap B) $

$\rightarrow x \in (A \setminus B) \vee x \in (B \setminus A) \vee (x \in A \cap B$)

$ \rightarrow (x \in A \wedge x \notin B) \vee (x \in B \wedge x \notin A) \vee (x \in A \wedge x \in B)$

However I am stuck here, I do not know how to apply the distributive laws here.
Any help with the distributive laws would be highly appreciated.

Comment: $(x\in B \land x\not\in A)\lor(x\in A \land x\in B)\equiv (x\in B)\land (x\not\in A\lor x\in A)\equiv x\in B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for ease of writing I assume the following:

$$p : x \in A$$
and,
$$q: y \in B$$

Your last statement would be equivalent to the following:

$$(p \wedge \neg q) \vee (q \wedge \neg p) \vee (p \wedge q)$$

$$\equiv (p \wedge \neg q) \vee (q \wedge \neg p) \vee (p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge q)$$

$$\equiv ((p \wedge \neg q) \vee (p \wedge q)) \vee ((q \wedge \neg p) \vee (q \wedge p)) $$

$$\equiv (p \wedge (q \vee \neg q)) \vee  (q \wedge (p \vee \neg p))$$

$$ \equiv p \vee q $$

$$= (x \in A) \vee (x \in B) \implies A \cup B$$

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

1. Each of $x\in A$ \ $B,\;x\in B$ \ $A,\;x\in A\cap B$ implies $(x\in A\lor x\in B).$ And $(x\in A\lor x\in B)\iff x\in A\cup B.$

So $$[(x\in A\setminus B)\lor(x\in B\setminus A)\lor (x\in A\cap B)]\implies x\in A\cup B.$$ 2. Now $x\in A\iff [(x\in A\land x\not\in B)\lor (x\in A\land x\in B)]\iff (x\in A \setminus B\lor x\in A\cap B).$

Similarly $x\in B\iff (x\in B$ \ $A \lor x\in B\cap A).$

So $$x\in A\cup B\implies (x\in A\lor x\in B)\implies$$ $$\implies [(x\in A\setminus B\lor x\in A\cap B)\;\lor \; (x\in B\setminus A\lor x\in B\cap A)] \implies$$ $$\implies [(x\in A\setminus B\lor x\in B\setminus A)\;\lor \;(x\in B\cap A\lor x\in A\cap B)] \implies$$ $$\implies (x\in A\setminus B\,\lor \, x\in B\setminus A\,\lor \, x\in A\cap B).$$

Comment: Thank you so mich for the detailed answer.